# Phbricator - Git PUSH hangs

Tags: phabricator

I finally got Phabricator installed and Git over SSH sort of working, I can clone down a repository fine, however when it comes to `push` the repository I end up with the following:

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

Counting objects: 391, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (383/383), done.
Writing objects:  88% (345/391), 2.87 MiB | 1.28 MiB/s
```

It always hangs on 88% and doesn't progress from there.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a permissions issue (although it's not obvious), adding write access for all users to the repo directory seemed to fix it:

```
chmod -R a+rw /var/repo
```

I should probably get more granular and restrict it to the correct user groups but for now this will suffice.